# How do I make animation positions relative?

Tags: unity, animation

I have a "reload gun animation".

Currently, this animation makes the character move from its current position to position (0, 0, 0).
This doesn't make sense.

What you could I check to make sure that the positions are relative instead of absolute?

Answer (score 1):

The animations (unless blended or so) are ALWAYS absolute!

The problem that I was confronted with was the fact that the animation contained position (and rotation) for the root node (=game  object itself):

[image]

Once I removed them, it behaved as expected.